# Automatically run shell commands in Xampp

Tags: php, mysql, windows, xampp, autostart

I am very new to using XAMPP. I have configured in my settings for XAMPP to start automatically during windows start up.
   Normally in my shell in XAMPP, i do this command always

```
cd users/documents/myapp
users/documents/myapp: php artisan serve
```

Is there a way that i can make my XAMPP run this command anytime its auto starts on my computer?

PS: Apologies for my bad english and i am newbie to XAMPP and server side stuff

Comment: You could add category "windows autostart" or something resembling.

Comment: @David, i don't understand your statement please

Comment: have a look at the categories below your question ;-)

Comment: Do you have the path to php in your PATH-variable of the windows configuration?
Else provide the path to Xampp ( C:\xampp or something else )

Comment: @David, yes i have the path to php in Environment Variables of my windows. If i provide to Xampp, how would be executed automatically?

Comment: You need a batch-file with the command to start and that file you can call by windows on start-up.
A batch-file could have a filename like this `phpAutostartCommand.bat`

Comment: xampp itself has many batch-files, i.e. to start apache manually.
You can create your's in the same kind and just call php in the same kind like on commandline. By double-click on the file you can first test if it's working. Afterwards add it to the autostart-folder